# Starting processes with different unlocked keychains on MacOS

Tags: macos, keychain, xcodebuild

As described in question [CLI: Switch keychains in order to sign an xcodebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535832) I have the problem of having to use two keychains for running `xcodebuild`. I need this because our enterprise & appstore identities are called the same.

When I try the proposed solution it works fine, if I'm running only one `xcodebuild`at a time. But I'm using a buildserver (hudson or jenkins) running multiple builds in parallel. Each build job should build the enterprise and the appstore version of an app, therefore it has to use different keychains. When changing the keychain list as proposed, this always affects all running processes of the current user. Therefore parallel builds of different projects would be affected and basically fail or use the wrong keychain.

I've tried several workarounds to open a new security context, which seems to host the keychain information:

- I used `login -f ...` to start a new login session, hoping it will use an independent security context. But when I change the keychain settings in the session it also affects the other login session.
- I used `ssh localhost ...` to start a new login session, but unfortunately with the same result.

It seems, that the security context is bound to the user and not to a dedicated session. Unfortunately I cannot find any information about those security contexts using Google.

Is there any way to run several processes for a dedicated user having different keychains active and unlocked?