# Errors converting xcarchive to IPA - single-bundle archive + missing plist method values

Tags: ios, plist, xcodebuild, ipa, xcarchive

I'm trying to convert my *xcarchive* to an IPA (XCode 7.1.1). The following command

```
xcodebuild 
    -exportArchive -archivePath foo.xcarchive -exportPath . -exportFormat IPA
```

Fails with the error

> the archive at path 'foo.xcarchive' is not a single-bundle archive

Since the above command is technically deprecated, I also tried the new form:

```
xcodebuild 
    -exportArchive -archivePath foo.xcarchive -exportPath . 
    -exportOptionsPlist ipa.plist
```

Where the `ipa.plist` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Which then resulted in the error:

> error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method':
>   expected one of {}, but found app-store

Now, trying to debug this I opened the xcarchive folder and inspected its structure. I noticed that I have a folder on the same level as `Products\Applications\foo.app` so I deleted it and tried again to no avail (same results). I then proceeded to delete files from within foo.app until I remained with nothing but the DWARF binary - still no cigar (same result), though that could have been due to the fact that I messed up the app signature by deleting files manually.

Comment: Are you sure the archive has been correctly found? Try to use absolute paths everywhere.

Comment: @Sulthan I'm sure because when I ended up deleting the `.app` itself inside the archive the error changed, so I know it's looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of our post-build steps left a stray folder in the `TARGET_BUILD_DIR`. This caused the generated `xcarchive` to be formatted as the dreaded *generic archive*. My attempts to delete the folder after the fact from the `xcarchive` itself were doomed to fail since the `xcarchive` has been flagged *generic* at the moment of its creation (as evidenced by some missing `Info.plist` fields). Once I made sure `TARGET_BUILD_DIR` contained only the `.app` after all the build phases were said and done, the generated `xcarchive` was formatted properly as an *iOS app archive*. That `xcarchive`, in turn, was easily exported to a proper IPA via `xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportPlistOptions`, which is the officially supported Apple recommendation that takes care of all the problematic SWIFT support folders and the like.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to solve the same problem, can you please tell me, how and where did you changed the TARGET_BUILD_DIR? 
My problem seems pretty similar, I have reduced Info.plist and in folder Products I have 2 folders -> Applications (which I want) and Users/... with some exported headers and libs, which I don't want. Thank you really much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Apple got back to me with a solution. As of Xcode 7 we should use xcodebuild instead of PackageApplication to produce the `.ipa` file.

xcodebuild has a new `-exportArchive` option to create an `.ipa` that works more like Xcode Organizer.

So we should now:

1. build an archive with xcodebuild archive
2. create the `.ipa` with xcodebuild `-exportArchive`

**We now build the archive like this:**

```
xcodebuild -workspace myApp.xcworkspace -scheme myApp -sdk iphoneos -configuration AppStoreDistribution archive -archivePath $PWD/build/myApp.xcarchive
```

**We now export the .ipa like this:**

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/build/myApp.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -exportPath $PWD/build
```

These two command create the files build/myApp.xcarchive and build/myApp.ipa

Note that xcodebuild `-exportArchive` requires a `-exportOptionsPlist` argument that points to a .plist file with export options. For a complete list of what you can put in that plist, run xcodebuild -help. The minimal contents of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>YOUR_TEN_CHARACTER_TEAM_ID</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Have you read the question? This is exactly what I'm doing. The export command doesn't work, and I'm trying to figure out why. It seems it's due to multiple folders being created in the `Product/Applications` folder and an `info.plist` that's missing some values in the root.

Answer (score 1):

Since the way you are creating an IPA is deprecated, you should do the following instead:

```
xcodebuild -scheme "Foo" -configuration Release clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Foo Corporation" -derivedDataPath "/path/to/some/folder/"

xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "/path/to/some/folder/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/foo.app" -o "/path/to/some/folder/foo.ipa"
```

Make sure you replace "Foo" with your schema name, and "iPhone Distribution: Foo Corporation" with your signing identity. And "/path/to/some/folder/" should be some build folder.

Comment: `xcodebuild -exportFormat` is deprecated, yes, but `PackageApplication` is deprecated too :) It creates packages that are rejected from the App Store due to a deprecated plist value (`CFBundleResourceSpecification`,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763288/ios-builds-ipa-creation-no-longer-works-from-the-command-line), and in the case of swift use, missing `SwiftSupport` folder (http://encyclopediaofdaniel.com/blog/xcarchive-to-ipa). The officially supported way is `xcodebuild -exportOptionsPlist` but unfortunately I can't get it to work so I'm using workarounds...

Comment: The workarounds being: (1) modify `PackageApplication` manually (as detailed in link) (2) Copy SwiftSupport folder using a somewhat hacky script (https://github.com/bq/ipa-packager).

Comment: And just to clarify - the xcarchive itself does not suffer from the issues I mentioned above (`CFBundleResourceSpecification`, `SwiftSupport`) but it doesn't do me much good as long as I can't produce a proper IPA from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute paths as parameters to `xcodebuild` options rather than relative paths.

So something like this:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "$PWD/foo.xcarchive" \
-exportPath "$PWD" -exportOptionsPlist "$PWD/ipa.plist"
```

As long as your `.xcarchive` is intact and signed correctly, that should work.  This is what I'm using in my build system.

Comment: it's not it, it seems there is a problem in the xcarchive that has to do with an invalid plist file and multiple folders in the `Product/Applications` path.

Answer (score 0):

I got some similar strange errors from XCode 7.2 when building for the simulator on the command line. You could try to either add `-sdk iphoneos` to your `xcodebuild` command (in order to skip simulator builds), or add something like `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest'` if you're building for the simulator.

Comment: I can't use `-sdk iphoneos` because I have a watch target that uses the Watch OS.

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched to using the fastlane `gym` tool to build and create ipa files...  I had a problem where one command line worked for making ad-hoc builds and I needed a different config to make app store builds and couldn't resolve it.  The fastlane stuff pretty much worked out of the box.

https://github.com/fastlane/gym

Comment: I actually need the xcarchive - can gym do that?

Comment: I think it does... The site says:  "All archives are stored and accessible in the Xcode Organizer".

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty since this is the most appropriate answer, though it is unlikely I will go this route due to past experience with "xcodebuild wrappers" - it's just a matter of time until they break with a new xcode release and/or certain build features you're using.I also doubt gym will solve my problem here, which is probably due to some folder generated in the target directory in one of our build phases.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the fastlane tools are getting some momentum, so they stand a good chance of passing the test of time.  There's a bunch of other useful stuff there for other annoying processes too, like provisioning profiles, and automating screen shot generation.  Hope you have success in your quest!

Comment: Thanks, but that's what they said about `xctool`, and when we moved to XCode 7 we eventually had to drop it... We'll stick with `xcodebuild` and `xcpretty` for now :)

Comment: The `gym` thing is useful, but I agree with you it'd be nicer to just use Apple native commands. You can use `gym` output to decipher what `xcodebuild` invocations it's doing underneath though. It's all about calling `xcrun` and `xcodebuild`

Answer (score 0):

The archive at path `foo.xcarchive` is not a single-bundle archive.

About this error:

1. check edit scheme -> Build
2. untick other targets, including Analyze, Test, Run, Profile, Archive
3. `xcodebuild` the archive
4. export the archive again